# Problem rotating a GameObject with a quaternion rotation by another quaternion

Tags: c++, 3d, rotation, quaternions

I am making a Videogame Engine for a College Subject and I implemented a 3d camera icons to show where the gameobjects without mesh but with a component camera are.

https://i.gyazo.com/5cd944b8f1c3d3e08aea4c440d294a36.mp4

Here's how it rotates now. The goal is to make the camera rotate just like now but looking to the frustum front, so i should make the camera mesh rotate 90 degrees to the right.

How can I make my original quaternion rotate 90 degrees to the right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One of the core aspects of why quaternions are used to represent rotations in games (and other applications) is that you can chain them very easily by multiplying them. So, by creating a quaternion that rotates 90 degrees to the right, and multiplying that with your rotation quaternion, you get a quaternion that does both.

Notice that order matters here, so `Quaternion(90 degree to the right) * YourQuaternion` will yield a different result than `YourQuaternion * Quaternion(90 degree to the right)`, similar to how you end up with a different rotation in the real world, depending on the order you're applying the rotations. In terms of quaternions, the rightmost rotation is "applied first", so your "90 degrees to the right" quaternion should be on the right side of the multiply sign.

Comment: Very useful commentary! Thanks, I used this [website](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToQuaternion/steps/index.htm) to look the rotation quaternions.

Comment: @VíctorSeguraBlanco I can also recommend [this](https://eater.net/quaternions) website with interactive videos (by the yt channel 3Blue1Brown), that explains a lot of how quaternions work and how they are used to rotate things, etc, and since they are interactive, you can try yourself how each value change the outcome.